# Jetpack compose java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid applier

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
2022-01-06 17:52:16.567 9504-9504/com.example.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android, PID: 9504
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid applier
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposablesKt.invalidApplier(Composables.kt:449)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.layout.LazyListKt.LazyColumn-EiNPFjs(LazyList.kt:265)
        at com.example.android.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:60)
        at com.example.android.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme_androidKt.PlatformMaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.android.kt:23)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:82)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:265)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
        at com.example.android.ui.theme.ThemeKt.PeopleInSpaceTheme(Theme.kt:41)
        at com.example.android.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:59)
        at com.example.android.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:49)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:410)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:166)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
2022-01-06 17:52:16.567 9504-9504/com.example.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3337)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2582)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2522)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:478)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:748)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:907)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:994)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20753)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8653)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be import wrong package from glance.

Google provide [glance](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/glance) for write appwidget with compose.

For example `LazyColumn`, there are:

- androidx.glance.appwidget.layout.LazyColumn
- androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn